# ALB Ingress - Redirect Traffic from HTTP to HTTPS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to route all `HTTP` traffic to `HTTPS`. I have a ALB ingress resource and following the guide here https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/tasks/ssl_redirect/#how-it-works  but its not working. When i try to access http://www.myhost.in it stays with http but does not redirect to `https`

below is my ingress resource file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: eks-learning-ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn878ef678df
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
  labels:
    app: eks-learning-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.myhost.in
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: eks-learning-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Any help in this would be really great, Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this post. I was missing adding this as my http paths. Have in mind this needs to be the first specified path.

```
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: ssl-redirect
            servicePort: use-annotation
```

Once i added this redirection started working.

So the final config in question should look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: eks-learning-ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn878ef678df
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
  labels:
    app: eks-learning-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.myhost.in
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: ssl-redirect
            servicePort: use-annotation
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: eks-learning-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Do you only expose port 80 on the service? or do I also need to set up port 443?

Comment: It's right in the doc https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/tasks/ssl_redirect/ But looking at that it seems that `ssl-redirect` is some example service. Not sure why they use annotation and then a dummy service. Doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: This answer is obsolete now. The approach is not working anymore. See this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037420/7820212

Answer (score 24):

AWS ALB Ingress controller now has added a new annotation for a easy redirection of HTTP requests to HTTPS. Available in `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`

This new annotation called as `ssl-redirect` is available in [ALB Controller v2.4](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/ingress/annotations/#ssl-redirect)

So your problem can be fixed just with the following 2 annotations.

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
```

No need to mention any ingress rules.

Complete example-

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
  labels:
    name: myapp
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-alb-group  #Use this to share ALB among multiple ingresses. #CostEffective
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: my-alb  # give ALB a meaningfull name otherwise a random name is assigned by AWS.
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:XXXX:certificate/YYYY" # Get it by $ aws acm list-certificates 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
  - host: app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! I was wondering if I still needed to include the old `ssl-redirect` path when using the annotation method. Guess not and seems to be working fine without it!

Comment: @skupjoe No, you don't need to specify `ssl-redirect` path. This annotation is sufficient.

Comment: perfectly working

Comment: Is there a way if I want to add a redirect for only a specific rule. AWS degrades fuctionality instead of improving it.

Comment: @GJoshi No, That's not possible. You need to use another alb or alb-group for that specific rule.

As per docs-

- ssl-redirect is exclusive across all Ingresses in IngressGroup.
- Once defined on a single Ingress, it impacts every Ingress within IngressGroup.
- Once enabled,  SSLRedirect, every HTTP listener will be configured with default action which redirects to HTTPS, other rules will be ignored.

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone else is setting up a cluster with a newer API version; `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`, where the syntax is different, this is the way to go:

```
  - path: /
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
      service:
        name: ssl-redirect
        port:
          name: use-annotation
```

**Note:** `path` must not contain a wildcard, as you are using `pathType: Prefix` that will fail to configure the ALB.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/pull/2274

Description

Controller v2.2.0 and later provides a simpler way to configure SSL redirection via the annotation alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect.

alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'