# SSL configuration for ingress in aws EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have two domains and both of these domains have separate SSL certificates. Is it possible to set up ssl for these domains using a single ingress configuration?

Cluster: EKS

Ingress controller: AWS ALB ingress controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in annotations comma-separated string of your certs.

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxxx:certificate/cert1,arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxxx:certificate/cert2,arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxxx:certificate/cert3
```

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/blob/main/docs/guide/ingress/annotations.md#certificate-arn

Also, you can assign a certificate via AWS web console:
EC2 -> load balancers -> listeners -> tls:443 -> view/edit certificates and add there an additional cert from ACM

Comment: Thanks. it worked.

I also have to add this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928651/19505219